# Uber API reports JSON is invalid for /requests/estimates endpoint

Tags: python, json, heroku, uber-api

I have made a fork of the Uber Application for Heroku

My Fork: https://github.com/CuriosityGym/Python-Sample-Application

I have modified the original code and the  /price URL to get me estimates of price for a specific product ID, using the /requests/estimates endpoint documented here https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post.

```
@app.route('/price', methods=['GET'])
def price():
"""Example call to the price estimates endpoint.

    Returns the time estimates from the given lat/lng given below.
    """
url = config.get('base_uber_url') + 'requests/estimate'
params = {
    "product_id": "83941b0d-4be1-4979-a9c0-f0af5ee2b89b",
    "start_latitude": config.get('start_latitude'),
    "start_longitude": config.get('start_longitude'),
    "end_latitude": config.get('end_latitude'),
    "end_longitude": config.get('end_longitude')
}
print params
print generate_ride_headers(session.get('access_token'))
response = app.requests_session.post(
    url,
    headers=generate_ride_headers(session.get('access_token')),
    data=params
)


return render_template(
    'results.html',
    endpoint='price',
    data=response.text,
)
```

Here is the snippet of my code  which uses the 1.2 version of the Uber Api. Other end points are working fine, its this one that does not work.

The print statements print to the Heroku logs and this is the output

```
{'product_id': '83941b0d-4be1-4979-a9c0-f0af5ee2b89b', 'end_longitude': '72.8811862', 'start_latitude': '18.936404', 'end_latitude': '19.0822507', 'start_longitude': '72.832546'}

{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer KA.eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjkgsdshdJpZCI6IkNmcjAvRzhrUUNPaDNhSnRsUVZ6QlE9PSIsImV4cGlyZXNfYXQiOjE1MTAzMjA3NzgsInBpcGVsaW5lX2tleV9pZCI6Ik1RPT0iLCJwaXBlbGluZV9pZCI6MX0.JDoDTgaYJitK8Rtr35C6gTh5IQc7-P4T7mGg_wOYXu0'}
```

The error Reported by the api is

{"message":"Unable to parse JSON in request body.","code":"invalid_json"}

Comment: JSON does not allow single quotation marks.

Comment: ...and BTW did you really post your access token here?

Comment: Nope, that access token has been modified.

Comment: My code has double quotation marks, I was wondering how they ended up being single.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode your json as a string. Luckily requests can do this for you or you can use `json.dumps()` to dump the object as a string.

Here are two examples:

Either do this:

```
import json

response = app.requests_session.post(
url,
headers=generate_ride_headers(session.get('access_token')),
data=json.dumps(params)
```

)

Or pass it as a kwarg json:

```
response = app.requests_session.post(
    url,
    headers=generate_ride_headers(session.get('access_token')),
    json=params
)
```

Comment: I tried both of them, and the first solution works brilliantly. In addition to the changes mentioned, I changed all double quotes in my params json to single quotes.